# How to see entire job step output?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

We have a SQL Agent job running some PowerShell, which creates a pretty long output (it has robocopy output, among other things).

In the SQL Agent Job History, we only see the first 1,000 characters or so of this output.

1. Is there another place we can look that will have the entire output?
2. Is there another approach that should be used to see the full output?

Comment: You can use Output file in sql agent job properties --> Advanced.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the job step advanced properties, **send output to a flat file** by inputing the "Output file" location and filename.  That should include all of your output for later viewing.

Or, if you want all of the output directly in the history of the job, you can select the check box "**Include step output in history**".  It'll use history entry rollover to include all of the data.  That might be a little cumbersome in looking at after-the-fact, though, but still effective.

Comment: If we send to flat file, does that get overwritten every job, or appended to?   Yes, sending output to history is cumbersome to read, but it has the advantage of being easy to turn on and off. (and it gets cleaned up by history cleanup...)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1394/how-to-store-longer-sql-agent-job-step-output-messages/) solution (for beginners like me) was the best for me:

The only detail is that in order to get the information I executed the stored procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobsteplog @job_name = N'test2';
```

I should be thinking about how to get this info when I don't have enough data space.